How do make a custom command to be executed directly from a folder using bash
I want to create a custom command that executes a bash script when a use types it in the terminal. So for example when they type in project setup it executes the setup bash script and then they can call project run1 and it executes the run1 script. However, I want to be able to do this when a user directly downloads my folder (from github specifically) they should be able to go into that folder and then run those commands and others starting with project and then the specific script name. They should be able to do this without any extra setup just downloading the github project and then they should be able to jump right in.
I know how to make custom commands, but I have to add stuff to .zshrc or set the source and then make it executable. I don't know how to do that stuff on other platforms like windows and I would like my bash scripts to run on any platform. I've tried to look a bunch of way to do this, but they all are just creating normal custom commands whereas I would like to just be able to add a folder with my bash scripts to my main folder and be able to call those from the command line with no extra setup on the user downloading it.

bash and zsh are 2 completely different shells. You tagged your question with bash but said "I have to add stuff to .zshrc" and .zshrc is a file specific to zsh, not bash (which has .bashrc instead). Please [edit] your question text and/or tag to be consistent with respect to each other and accurate with respect to which shell you are using. Also add a [mcve] including your code and sample input/output so we can help you with that, see [ask].

Do you understand about the $PATH variable, and the difference between myscript  args... ; ./myscript args... ; partial/path/to/myscript and /full/path/to/myscript ? Those alternates should solve your problem. Good luck.

What if 'any platform' doesn't have/support bash ? ( Also, why are you still referring to zsh in your post).


I want to be able to do this when a user directly downloads my folder (from github specifically) they should be able to go into that folder and then run those commands and others starting with project and then the specific script name. They should be able to do this without any extra setup just downloading the github project and then they should be able to jump right in.

As described, this is not possible with any of the common Unix shells.  It would require the current working directory and / or your project directory to be in the executable search path, and you do not get that just from copying or unpacking or downloading a folder.
And personally, I wouldn't want that anyway.  I'm sure there are things that would turn me off from your project faster or more strongly, but you messing with my operating environment without my prior knowledge and approval would turn me off quickly.  If I were feeling kind then I might file a bug report about it instead of just going away silently.  But that's all speculative because, again, you can't do that.
A common approach would be to provide an environment configuration script that users could source to modify their path as you want, or whatever.  That's shell-specific, of course, but you're in shell-specific territory in any case.
